# LaTeX Error: File 'moderncv.cls' not found

Tags: miktex, moderncv, cv

I tried to write my CV using `moderncv` class with MikTeX 2.9, but it doesn't work.

[image]

I tried to:

1. Install manually the package from my computer:

[image]

2. Install from the Internet:

[image]

3. Writing the file name:

[image]

4. From the MikTeX Package Manager

[image]

And always I get an error.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! When you tried to install the package, it has to be installed from a repository. A priori, it is not in `C\Program Files\…` but a repository on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are several missunderstandings:

1. A basic installation of MiKTeX does not contain class `moderncv`, you have to install it from a repository in the internet, **not** a local one.
2. To get proper error messages please do **not** use `PDFTexify`, use the usual compiling chain `pdflatex`, `bibtex` or `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.
3. It seems your MiKTeX distribution is a little bit outdated because now MiKTeX Console is used instead of MiKTeX Package manager. So please update first your MiKTeX distribution with MiKTeX package Manager to the current one (you need to use a repository from the internet!), then update your basic MiKTeX to the complete MiKTeX with MiKTeX Console. Then you will also have the current version 2.2.0 of class `moderncv` installed.
4. If you can't use your MiKTeX Package Manager because the error message that you have a damaged configuration file, uninstall MiKTeX completly and install it new with the Netinstaller for complete MiKTeX you can download from the MiKTeX homepage. This new complete MiKTeX contains class `moderncv` and the new MiKTeX Console ...